# Problemas al crear rutas en Angular

Tags: angular, rutas

estoy creando rutas para poder enlazar dos component que son UsuarioComponent y RegistrarComponent, pero al ingresar la ruta en el navegador no me cambia ,sigue mostrando la misma pestaña de usuario que es la principal ; ¿Qué error estoy cometiendo?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsuarioComponent } from './usuario/usuario.component';
import { RegistrarComponent } from './registrar/registrar.component';
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
  

  const routes:Routes=[
    {path:'',redirectTo:'/usuario',pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'usuario/registrar',component:RegistrarComponent}
    
  ]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsuarioComponent,
    RegistrarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

El orden de las rutas es importante porque el enrutador utiliza una estrategia de gana la primera coincidencia al hacer coincidir rutas, por lo que las rutas más específicas deben colocarse antes de las rutas menos específicas.

```
const routes:Routes=[
    {path:'usuario/registrar',component:RegistrarComponent}
    {path:'',redirectTo:'/usuario',pathMatch:'full'},
    
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con Lobos, solo quisiera aclarar que es mejor especificar cada ruta, y al final realizar una validación de la siguiente manera:

```
const routes: Routes=[
    {
     path:'usuario',
     component: UsuarioComponent
    },
    {
     path:'usuario/registrar',
     component:RegistrarComponent
    },
    {
     path: '**',
     redirectTo: UsuarioComponent
    },
]
```

Lo que se hace con los ** es que todo lo que no este definido en la constante **routes** lo dirija hacia **UsuarioComponent**